# Do the rank and file nuns have any supernatural abilities?

Tags: warrior-nun

Among the warrior nuns in the eponymous series, the bearer of the Halo explicitly has supernatural abilities, including, so far as I can tell, durability, strength, intangibility, rapid healing, and other abilities depending on the particular bearer.

That said, the other nuns have demonstrated some impressive combat abilities. For instance, one nun  (not even Lilith, whom I presume is one of the top warriors) defeated 5-6 trained individuals in single combat, and, perhaps more notably, seemingly deflected a bullet or two with a rod.

Does the faith of the other nuns (those without the Halo) grant them any combat abilities beyond those of mere mortals? Or is this just the product of good training?

Answer (score 2):

From everything we've seen in season 1 and 2 so far, the other nuns are just extremely trained, they have no powers. They can't even see some of the demons and have to rely on the warrior nun to tell them where and what they are facing (as shown with the wraith demons several times in season 1)